# IntelliJ - Gradle - Kotlin - Micronaut - Changing files does not re-generate classes on "run"

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, micronaut

I have a Kotlin-Micronaut v.1.0.2 project in IntelliJ and with Gradle v5.3.
My running application has for example the following controller:

```
@Controller("/api/test")
class TestController {

    @Get
    fun helloWorld() = "Hello World"
}
```

In case I change any of this code, for example change the return value or add another REST method (e.g. POST), the necessary code will only be generated on a `./gradlew clean build`. Hitting "Run" in IntelliJ will not generate the necessary endpoints for me (e.g. on adding a POST endpoint and trying to curl it, I get "Method not allowed" until I clean build).

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Try Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle** option. Does it help?

Comment: Hey @Andrey I applied the menu setting you mentioned and now it works. Thank you. If I could, I'd mark your answer ans the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle** option. This way IDE will use Gradle to generate and build classes according to logic of Gradle plugins you are using.